# blinking text on data-bond - html

Tags: html, text

I want a text to blink so that it catches users attention.

the following is the code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <div id="placeMap" class="placeMap" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
      <div data-bind="if: showSubmit">Drag the map pin or enter a new address to change the location</div>
    </div>
```

I want to blink the "Drag the mao pin....change the location"

That line shows up only when the submit button is enabled.

Comment: as a user... I **really** hate it when websites do that...

Comment: i too am not fond of blinking texts but the customer requires it :(

Comment: ah customers... it would be sooo much easier if we didn't have them... (oh wait). :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS3:

```
.blinkingText {
    animation: 1 blink 1s step-end infinite
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {background-color: blue}
    50% {background-color: black}
}
```